# TCP Communication+ Java Socket + ReadTimeoutException

Tags: sockets, tcp, inputstream, socketexception, datainputstream

I am deploying my application in Tandem System (Unix environment). I am trying to connect to other application using TCP. I have a IP adress and Port number. from client (my application), I am writing data, looks like it's working (Not getting any Exception) but while reading data, I am getting ReadTimeOutException. Below is my program,  I will appreciate your help. There is the same application which is return is C++ it's working fine with the same IP Address and Port number

```
                Socket clientSocket = new Socket();
                clientSocket.setKeepAlive(true);
                clientSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
                clientSocket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
                clientSocket.setSoTimeout(120000); 
                clientSocket.setSendBufferSize(65535);
               clientSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("Server IP", "Port Number"), 1000);
                OutputStream outstream = clientSocket.getOutputStream(); 
                outstream .writeInt(msgLen);
                dout.write(msg, 0, msgLen);
                dout.flush();

                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                 int len = din.readInt();
                 data = new byte[len];
                 dis .readFully(data);
```

Its Throwing an Error while reading it.
Timeout while attempting to establish socket connection.
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

===========================

```
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket();
        clientSocket.setKeepAlive(true);
        clientSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
        clientSocket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
        clientSocket.setSoTimeout(120000); // Should wait 3 minutes before throwing time out exception - Actually throwing after 2 minutes
        clientSocket.setSendBufferSize(65535);

    InputStream in= new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    OutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    out.write(byteArray);
    out.flush();


 // Receive the same string back from the server
    int totalBytesRcvd = 0;  // Total bytes received so far
    int bytesRcvd;           // Bytes received in last read
    while (totalBytesRcvd < byteArray.length) {
      if ((bytesRcvd = in.read(byteArray, totalBytesRcvd,  
                      byteArray.length - totalBytesRcvd)) == -1)
        throw new SocketException("Connection close prematurely");
      totalBytesRcvd += bytesRcvd;
    }


    clientSocket .close();  // Close the socket and its streams
```

Please help me with this problem, I am stuck on this since last week.

Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

- It isn't throwing that exception 'while attempting to establish the connection'. It is throwing it at some read call, almost certainly inside the constructor for `ObjectInputStream.` You should have included the stack trace in your question.
- You need to create the `ObjectOutputStream` *before* the `ObjectInputStream.`
- 12000 milliseconds is two minutes, not three.
- You should use `readFully()` at the client, just like you're doing in the server.

Comment: Thank you for your replay,  Let me make the changes and try accordingly.  1)   I also find out that..the other program (C++) which is running fine, It's using this command to set the IP Address export TCPIP_PROCESS=\$StakeName . So C++ program able to find a IP Addess and sending the Data to thirdParty System.   2)I think  The  problem is ThirdParty System, I am calling from my server don't have an access, I have to use different IP Address to connect to Pass the data to TCP IP. like above is there any way.. I can do the export in java and use different IP Address to connect.

Comment: My Server is the ThirdParty Program I don't know the language I am communicating using TCP.